# How to get the correlated values of a dataset in a seperate column if the index and the columns are same

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I imported a dataset into my python script and took the correlation. This is the code for correlation:

```
data = pd.read_excel('RQ_ID_Grouping.xlsx' , 'Sheet1')
corr = data.corr()
```

After the correlation the data looks like this:

[image]

I want to convert the data into below format:

[image]

I am using this code to achieve the above data  , but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
corr1 = (corr.melt(var_name = 'X' , value_name = 'Y').groupby('X')['Y'].reset_index(name = 'Corr_Value'))
```

I know there should be something after the 'groupby' part but I don't know what . If you could help me , I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape and drop missing values, convert `MultiIndex` to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last set columns names:

```
df = corr.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['X','Y','Corr_Value']
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = corr.stack().rename_axis(('X','Y')).reset_index(name='Corr_Value')
```

And your solution with `melt` is also possible:

```
df = (corr.rename_axis('X')
         .reset_index()
         .melt('X', var_name='Y', value_name='Corr_Value')
         .dropna()
         .sort_values(['X','Y'])
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```